# Looking to get the average time between event dates for each ID

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a sample dataset:

```
  patient_id                                event_description     
    A                                             DiagnosisA          2016-01-15
    A                                             DiagnosisA          2016-02-10
    A                                             DiagnosisA          2016-02-20
    A                                             DiagnosisA          2016-03-02
    B                                             DiagnosisA          2016-08-15
    B                                             DiagnosisA          2016-08-20
    B                                             DiagnosisA          2016-09-20
    B                                             DiagnosisA          2016-10-10
    C                                             DiagnosisA          2016-10-15
```

This is obviously a sample of the dataset, the entire dataset includes approx 2 million patients. What I'd like to do is find the average time between diagnosis for each patient.

Comment: but there's no time values - only dates, elaborate your question

Comment: `df.groupby('patient_id').apply(lambda x: x.diff().mean())`